# JPA OneToOne find all stuck in loop

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I've a Java REST API with JPA. Whenever I create an entity, I also want to create another entity with a forgein key. Or maybe someone can advise me otherwise, I would really appreciate it and learn from it =)
When i successfully create a company it will make a file entity in the database as well, so that works fine. but,
Whenever I execute a findAll method in the JPA repository it will give me a loop of the one company that i've created.
like this:

[image: findAll()]

If you need any more information, please let me know!

**Company.class**

```java
package nl.hulpvriend.dehulpvriend.company;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.*;
import nl.hulpvriend.dehulpvriend.file.File;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class Company {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull(message = "The company name cannot be empty")
    @Size(max = 30, message = "Company name cannot be longer than 30 characters")
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "Company must contain a service type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ServiceType serviceType;

    private double stars;

    private Integer pricePerHour;

    private String description;

    private String kvk;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private File file;


}
```

**File.class**

```java
package nl.hulpvriend.dehulpvriend.file;

import lombok.*;
import nl.hulpvriend.dehulpvriend.company.Company;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Data
public class File {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String fileId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId
    private Company company;

    @NotNull(message = "Must contain a data")
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;

    private String downloadUrl;

    private String fileName;

    private String fileType;

    public File(String fileName, String fileType, byte[] data) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileType = fileType;
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Fix spring boot one to many bidirectional infinity loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130173/how-to-fix-spring-boot-one-to-many-bidirectional-infinity-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add JsonIgnore to one of the references to break the loop:

For example in the File class:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapsId
private Company company;
```

Comment: Wow that really worked... I can't believe why java is such more complicated then .NET :/ 
Thank you so much, you really made my day :))

Comment: I'm curious How do you deal with circular references and serialization in .NET?